# Laravel read file content and keep the format

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

how to read file contents such as txt or json by keeping the format.

i already use this code :

```
File::get(storage_path('my_file.txt'))
```

the example is below : 
the original file :

```
<?php 
php_info();
?>
```

trimmed version :

```
<?php php_info(); ?>
```

but this static function return trimmed function. 
is there something i have been missing or is there any alternative and efficient way ?

thanks u

Comment: It's not trimmed. Line breaks don't have any meaning in HTML. You can use http://php.net/nl2br to add them, or output it in a `<pre>` tag to preserve the line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I already get solution using the native php  here the code :

```
      @php
         $file = storage_path('file.txt');
         $text = file_get_contents($file);
         $text = nl2br($text);
         echo '<pre>'.$text.'</pre>'; 
     @endphp
```

Hope it would help other